# having problem converting .ab file to .tar

Tags: android, adb, extract, android-backup-service, platform-tools

I extracted the package of the app **Dafit** successfully with ADB.
using this command,

`adb backup -apk com.crrepa.band.dafit`

with that command I got a file named **backup.ab**

Now I'm using abe.jar to convert that **.ab** into **.tar .**
I pasted **bacup.ab** and **abe.jar** into same folder and wrote this command in CMD

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_321\bin\java.exe" -jar abe.jar unpack backup.ab backup.tar`

when I press enter, this result is shown...

`49% 1024 bytes written to backup.tar.`

I get the **backup.tar** file in the folder, but when I try to open it, it gives this error..

[image]

Is there any problem with the process..? What should I do to open that **.tar** file..?

Comment: What program do you use for opening the tar archive? Windows by default does not contain a program that can handle tar archives. You have to install an archive program like 7-Zip, WinRAR, WinZip ... to open tar archives.

Comment: I'm using WinRAR.

Comment: Make sure the .ab file has content (size bigger than 1KB), otherwise the `adb backup` command has filed or the app disallows backup.

Comment: Size of the backup.ab file is 47 bytes only. Is there any problem with my backup? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: 47 bytes means backup file is empty (not sure why, at least the APK should be included, are you sure the app is really installed - check `adb shell pm list packages`). Check APK file if backup is allowed at all (in AndroidManifest.xml). Also check logcat for error messages. You can try to enable key-value backup https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232788/2241

Comment: Use a [binary editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/binary-editor?view=msvc-170) and check the content of the `.ab` file